# Why is GridView not displaying data inside a asp:Panel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have the following in my `Default.aspx` page (By default the `Status` tab and it's `content` is shown when the page loads):

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentMain">
    <div style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:BulletedList ID="tabs" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="#tab1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Your Tasks" Value="#tab2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Messages" Value="#tab3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Dependencies" Value="#tab4"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Documents" Value="#tab5"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pro-Forma" Value="#tab6"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Admin Controls" Value="#tab7"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:BulletedList>

        <asp:Panel ID="content" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <asp:Panel ID="tab1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A STATUS
                <asp:GridView ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="tab2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS YOUR TASKS
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="tab3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A MESSAGE</asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="tab4" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A DEPENDENCIES</asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="tab5" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A DOCUMENT</asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="tab6" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A PRO-FORMA</asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="tab7" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A ADMIN CONTROLS</asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The respective `content` is shown based on the tab that is clicked, which is controlled through JQuery. I am populating the `GridView` inside the Status tab content from code-behind for `Default.aspx`:

```
public void PullData()
{
    DataTable taskData = new DataTable();
    string connString = @"user id = myid1;" + "password= myP@$$w0Rd; server= dev-mag; database= Ob;" + "connection timeout=30";
    string query = @"SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
        FROM dbo.table13934";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
            da.Fill(taskData);
            //conn.Close();
            yourTasksGV.DataSource = taskData;
            yourTasksGV.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PullData();
}
```

When the page loads, the `content` just displays `THIS IS A STATUS` and nothing in the `GridView` but if I take the `GridView` out of the `content` and place anywhere else on the page, it shows the data that was retrieved from the SQL Query.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Debugger:

[image]

Not sure where the extra DIV is being created from :/

This is the Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
            $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
            $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

            $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
                $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
                $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
                //$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
                $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Not sure where the `JQuery################` is coming from...

Comment: are you setting `tab1.Visible = false` in the code behind?

Comment: Is there any jquery script or css that's making the visibility of the tab that has the gridview?

Comment: It is weird because when I look at the source, there is a DIV that is being added and being set as `Display: none`... hmmmmmmm I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the gridview displayed is because your jquery checks for `$("#content div:first").fadeIn();`

```
#content div // references your main panel and tab1 panel
```

And the html generates another `<div>` for the gridview itself which is not checked in your code. So change your script as below. I added `$("#content div div:first").fadeIn();` to both the conditions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
        $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

        $("#content div div:first").fadeIn(); // New code to show the gridview

        $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
            //$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();

            $("#content div div:first").fadeIn(); // New code to show the gridview
        });
    });
</script>
```

This should display the first tab with gridview upon page load and again when you click on the `Status` link. There could be more sophisticated solution than this but this is what I came up with based on your code approach.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have data. [See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext.aspx) to test if you have data or not

Comment: I do have Data as I can see it outside. I think somehow the CSS is making the DIV to hidden... :/

Comment: Nonetheless, I'd put there in your code. There is no harm to it.

Comment: Something to do with the setting hidden or visible through JQuery is causing the GridView to not show up?